Can I define anchors when converting PHP arrays to YAML?
I bring to you a problem regarding PHP and YAML anchors that I would like to solve using Symfony's Yaml component.
I'm supposed to build YAML files from PHP arrays, with anchors passing options from a main YAML to sub-YAMLs.
A simplified example:
I would like to get this YAML output:
templates: &options
  option1:
    name: Template 1
    file: template1.img
  option2:
    name: Template 2
    file: template2.img
  option3:
    name: Template 3
    file: template3.img
pages:
  front:
    file: front.yaml
    <<: *options
  back:
    file: back.yaml
    <<: *options

from an array similar to this:
array $bookCover = [
    "templates" => [
        "option1" => [
            "name" => "Template 1",
            "file" => "template1.img"
        ],
        "option2" => [
            "name" => "Template 2",
            "file" => "template2.img"
        ],
        "option3" => [
            "name" => "Template 3",
            "file" => "template3.img"
        ]
    ],
    "pages" => [
        "front" => [
            "file" => "front.yaml"
        ],
        "back" => [
            "file" => "back.yaml"
        ]
    ]
];

by, well, parsing the array to YAML using YAML::dump().
I tried a few options I saw, like splitting the array up into, for this example,  $templates[] and $pages[] and then referencing them in $bookCover[] like this:
array $templates = [
    "option1" => [
            "name" => "Template 1",
            "file" => "template1.img",
        ],
        "option2" => [
            "name" => "Template 2",
            "file" => "template2.img",
        ],
        "option3" => [
            "name" => "Template 3",
            "file" => "template3.img",
        ],
    ],
];

array $pages = [
    "front" => [
        "file" => "front.yaml",
        "<<" => $templates,
    ],
    "back" => [
        "file" => "back.yaml",
        "<<" => $templates,
    ],
];

array $bookCover = [
    "templates" => $templates,
    "pages" => $pages,
];

Parsing that to YAML gave me, as anyone could have guessed, the entire array as it would be logically built by PHP. The 'closest' result that I got through many similar attempts and shenanigans was this:
templates: 
  '&options':
    option1:
      name: Template 1
      file: template1.img
    option2:
      name: Template 2
      file: template2.img
    option3:
      name: Template 3
      file: template3.img
pages:
  front:
    file: front.yaml
    '<<': '*options'
  back:
    file: back.yaml
    '<<': '*options'

...which is still just wrong and frustrating.
I was not able to find anything of actual use online, other than official documentation and user guides detailing that for the other way around (parsing YAML to PHP), PHP will simply resolve the anchor by writing the contents of $bookCover["templates"] into $bookCover["pages"]["front"] and $bookCover["pages"]["back"] and be done with it...
I fear that I'll have to take out the regex bat to beat the anchor into the YAML string manually, but before it has to come to that, I'd like to ask if there are 'easier' options for achieving my goal here.
I'm relatively new to software development (as you can most likely tell from the way I wrote this), so please excuse me for not getting some of the terminology right...
If there are tips on how to write future questions, I'd also love to hear them!
Thank you in advance!
